# Fonts other than english are not getting displayed in tty terminals

Tags: fonts, tty

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 desktop system, and I have only tty terminal access to the system without any UI (bare minimal Ubuntu installation). I have a USB stick with files and folders in Chinese, and when I mount the USB stick and see its content using ls command, I can see just boxes instead of the Chinese fonts correctly. Is there any way to render Non-English characters on the terminal.

I tried different set of combinations with 'iocharset' and 'codepage' options in mount, but nothing seems to help.

Currently, the following locales are configured, with the LANG option set to en_US.UTF8.

```
en_US.UTF8
en_US.iso8859-1
zh_CN.gb2312
Zh_CN.UTF8
```

Note: When connecting the USB stick to a gnome-ubuntu system, it is displaying the fonts correctly on its terminal. It is just the tty terminal which is not displaying the Chinese characters.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to confirm this: Your 'note' at the end is related to a completely different installation, right?

Comment: I think it should be en_US.UTF-8 (missing dash).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install some additional package.
For begin you can try this one:

```
sudo apt-get install console-setup
```

Then you can change the font. You need to chose font with Chinese symbols.